# What does gradle classifier: 'core'?

Tags: java, gradle, hive, protobuf-java

I had conflict with the protobuf dependency of hive and another package that depends on protobuf. I solved the problem with "classifier: 'core'":

```
implementation group: 'org.apache.hive', name: 'hive-exec', version: '3.1.2', classifier: 'core'
```

But what this does? where does the term 'core' come from in this filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put simply its another filter criteria to get a sub-type for a GAV artifact in maven repository. useful when there are multiple flavours for a single artifact. Ex: jar per JDK version
see more https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/variant_model.html#understanding-variant-selection

Comment: where does the term 'core' come from in this filter?

Comment: Go to https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hive/hive-exec/3.1.2/
    will list a jar called "hive-exec-3.1.2-core.jar" and the use of classifier: 'core' points to this simplified jar which contains only hive dependencies